# Scrapy export to .csv can't do line break

Tags: python, scrapy

I have managed to extract some data with the following program. I tried to export to .csv file with the following command, `scrapy crawl jp -t csv -o extract_jp.csv --loglevel=INFO.` However, if I didn't include `.replace('\n','').replace('\r','')` into the program, the content, i.e. 'question_content' can't write into the same cell but split into different cells.

**How can I make the content to keep their format with line breaks but present in the same cell?**

```
import scrapy

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
best_answer = scrapy.Field()
question_content = scrapy.Field()
question_title = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "jp"
allowed_domains = ['detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']

start_urls = [
    'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q' + str(x)
    for x in range (12174460000,12174470000)
]

def parse(self, response):
    item = JPItem()

    item['question_title'] = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ttl h1::text").extract_first()
    item['question_content'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p::text").extract()])
    item['best_answer'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdBA.othrAns.clrfx div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()])

    yield item
```

**Edit 1**

[LibreOffice Display after amendment of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU1tt.png)

**Edit 2**

[Unable to catch the html link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBgvQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with your CSV-reading software.

I'm able to extract and display in LibreOffice just fine.

This is the spider I used (adapted from yours):

```
import scrapy

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
    question_title = scrapy.Field()
    question_content = scrapy.Field()
    best_answer = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "jp"
    allowed_domains = ['detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']
    start_urls = [
        'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12174467757',
        'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10174455955',
        'https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14174286904',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = JPItem()

        item['question_title'] = response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ttl h1::text").extract_first()
        item['question_content'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p::text").extract()])
        item['best_answer'] = ''.join([i for i in response.css("div.mdPstd.mdPstdBA.othrAns.clrfx div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()])

        yield item
```

I'm calling it with `$ scrapy runspider myspider.py -o test.csv`

And this is what LibreOffice displays: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqCV4.jpg

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answers. It did happen to the csv reading software issue. Yet, when I tun my program, it will generate a line break between the items. Do you know why? I have added the LibreOffice display to the question. Thanks

Comment: @KennedyKan, are you using Windows? If yes, you may be seeing this issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2672 .

Comment: @paultmbrth, thanks. Didn't realise could be Windows issue instead. Yet, when I check over the extract data, I realise I could not grab the href element (the url) included in <p> <p> for the 'question_content' in the first url due to the use of "::text". But if I omit the "::text", I will get other unrelated data. How can I do to just also grab that link?

Comment: @KennedyKan, I suggest that you open another question only about selecting the data you need from the HTML response. `::text` (which is an extension to CSS from Scrapy) selects text nodes. An `href` attribute of an `<a>` is not a text node. You can play (in `scrapy shell`) with `div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p a`, `div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes p a::attr(href)`, or `div.mdPstd.mdPstdQstn.sttsRslvd.clrfx div.ptsQes ::attr(href)`

Comment: Thanks for your along. It definitely helps a lot. Thanks